# How to remain the first column value as shown in the dataset that used to predict in flask python

Tags: python, csv, flask, deployment, lstm

I m currently working on my own project which use LSTM model to predict the time series data. I am able to predict the result and attach the predicted value to csv file but unfotunely i have lost my first column name and value, For example, the first column in the csv file I uploaded for prediction is the datetime, how to remain again the first column datatime after i have made prediction and download as a new csv file, Please share me some tips, its really stuck me for a while, So i would like to have some tips regarding this issues, Please give me some advice thanks and appreciate!

```
from flask import Flask, make_response, request, render_template
import io
from io import StringIO
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pickle
import os
from keras.models import load_model
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMAResults


app = Flask(__name__)





@app.route('/')
def form():
    return """
        <html>
            <body>
                <h1>Let's TRY to Predict..</h1>
                </br>
                </br>
                <p> Insert your CSV file and then download the Result
                <form action="/transform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" name="data_file" class="btn btn-block"/>
                    </br>
                    </br>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Predict</button>
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>
    """
@app.route('/transform', methods=["POST"])
def transform_view():
 if request.method == 'POST':
    f = request.files['data_file']
    if not f:
        return "No file"

    
    stream = io.StringIO(f.stream.read().decode("UTF8"), newline=None)
    csv_input = csv.reader(stream)
    #print("file contents: ", file_contents)
    #print(type(file_contents))
    print(csv_input)
    for row in csv_input:
        print(row)

    stream.seek(0)
    result = stream.read()
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(result), usecols=[1])

    # load the model from disk
    model = load_model('model.h5')
    dataset = df.values
    dataset = dataset.astype('float32')
    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
    dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

    dataset = np.reshape(dataset, (dataset.shape[0], 1, dataset.shape[1]))
    df = model.predict(dataset)
    transform = scaler.inverse_transform(df)    
    df_predict = pd.DataFrame(transform, columns=["predicted value"])
 
            

    response = make_response(df_predict.to_csv(index=True , encoding='utf8'))
    response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=result.csv"
    return response



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port = 9000, host = "localhost")
```

The first column was shown as 'Month' in sequence in the csv file I used to predict, and this is the result after predicted and download as a new csv file

[image: The original column was belong to 'Month']

Comment: that column the pandas dataframe index, not even really necessary. It looks like `df_predict = pd.DataFrame(transform, columns=["predicted value"])` is only writing that one column...

Comment: Yeah yeah, because it was month in sequence before predict and after I set the index = True in make response, so it returns the result the 2 columns, but unfortunately, it returns the first column in number sequence, so I have no idea how do deal with it, can you please share some tips to me

Comment: Please help @TenaciousB

Comment: `df['predicted_value'] = transform` might work

Comment: @TenaciousB need to replace any code or just add on only ?

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the csv file from upload by .copy() and from that copied csv just folter the required folder and concate with your prediction csv..simple.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).